# Recommended method to prevent any content inside iframe from setting cookies

Tags: javascript, iframe, cookies

I get the content to be put inside an iframe from a source I do not trust. For a particular need to be met, I want the content (which might include javascript) to be unable to set cookies at all. What is the recommended method to achieve that?

Edit: I recognize this is similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330906/disable-cookies-inside-a-frame-iframe). I should have mentioned this earlier, but the iframe has a cross-origin source. I want to disable the content inside from setting cookies even on its own source. Does sandboxing achieve that? Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Disable Cookies Inside A Frame/Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330906/disable-cookies-inside-a-frame-iframe)

Comment: Yes, @yaitzme, sandboxing can achieve exactly that.  For more details and supporting resources, see my updated answer...

Answer (score 27, accepted):

## **The short answer:**

The HTML5 `sandbox` attribute **prevents an iframe from reading/writing cookies**.  This is true for both same-origin and cross-origin iframes.

The `allow-scripts` attribute enables JavaScript but does not interfere with restrictions on cookies.

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="..."></iframe>
```

## **The long answer:**

*So if you're not fully convinced, this one is for you...*

According to the [W3C Working Draft](https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox) (2010) and [W3C Recommendation](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxing) (2014), when the user agent (browser) parses the `sandbox` attribute, it has to add certain flags, which are then used to put restrictions on the content within the iframe.  One of those flags are meant to force the content into a unique origin, and prevent it from reading/writing cookies:

> The `sandbox` attribute, when specified, enables a set of extra restrictions on any content hosted by the `iframe`.
>
> While the sandbox attribute is specified, the iframe element's nested browsing context must have the flags given in the following list set.
>
> ...
>
> ...
>
> **The sandboxed origin browsing context flag**, unless the sandbox attribute's value, when split on spaces, is found to have the allow-same-origin keyword set
>
> > This flag forces content into a unique origin, thus preventing it from accessing other content from the same origin.
> >
> > This flag also **prevents script from reading from or writing to the document.cookie IDL attribute**, and blocks access to localStorage. [WEBSTORAGE]

When a sandboxed iframe attempts to write a cookie, the following exception is raised:

> > Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'cookie' property on 'Document': The document is sandboxed and lacks the 'allow-same-origin' flag.

and no cookie is ever written.

Since the sandboxed iframe cannot write cookies at all, it will not be able to set cookies even on its originating site. 
 (In fact, this would be one of the use-cases for using the `allow-same-origin` keyword).

> The allow-same-origin attribute is intended for two cases.
>
> ...
>
> Second, it can be used to embed content from a third-party site, sandboxed to prevent that site from opening popup windows, etc, without preventing the embedded page from communicating back to its originating site, using the database APIs to store data, etc.

Comment: There is currently no value of the `sandbox` attribute that disables cookies. Cookies are primarily a function of HTTP, not Javascript.

Comment: @duskwuff:  The value added to this attribute was only meant to **enable** JavaScript, not to disable cookies.

Comment: The OP is asking to disable cookies. Neither the `sandbox` attribute, nor any value for it, will do that.

Comment: @duskwuff:  Are you sure about this? According to the W3C (https://www.w3.org/TR/2010/WD-html5-20100624/the-iframe-element.html#attr-iframe-sandbox), a sandboxed iframe (**without** `allow-same-origin`) should not be able to read/write cookies.  I have tested this, and found it to be true (at least with Google Chrome).

Comment: The question is asking about a cross-origin iframe. The attributes you're talking about only work for same-domain iframes, as far as I know.

Comment: The `sandbox` attribute is most often used with cross-origin iframes to restrict them from being potentially harmful.

Comment: @duskwuff:  Regarding the restrictions set on iframes using the `sandbox` attribute, it makes no difference whether the iframe is from the same domain or cross-origin.  If you look into the spec, you'll see.  I quoted some of it to support the facts.

Comment: Very helpful @ChavaG, thanks. However what could be the purpose of preventing *all* writing of cookies, even ones local to the iframe?  Cookies (without iframes) already have different security segregations, I don't see what it would hurt to have a sandbox write and read only it's own cookies.  At the least, it seems this permission should be separate from everything else implied by the flag, because it's not nearly the same as being able to access parent domain data.

Comment: Thanks for your elaborate explanation. Do you know if this restrictions also apply to the HTTP request of the iframe HTML document? I. e. are cookies sent in the request and/or set by the response? Thanks.

Comment: The restriction applies to both reading cookies and writing cookies. So cookies would not be sent in the HTTP request, and they would not be set by the HTTP response (even if the response contains the `set-cookie` header).
Cookies are stored and retrieved by the browser via the document.cookie IDL attribute. A sandboxed iframe cannot read from it, nor can it write to it.

Comment: @ernesto Does that answer your question?

Comment: An issue with the suggested solution is that it is not specific to cookies.

Comment: @Malvoz OP is asking how to prevent an iframe's content from reading or writing cookies. The answer is to use the `sandbox` attribute, which will accomplish exactly that. Do you have a similar question?

Comment: I tested this with a vimeo video - added &dnt=1 at the end of the url of the iframe and sandbox="allow-scripts" as an attribute and still getting a cookie... hm