# Is it possible to block cookies within an iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

Is it possible to force an iframe to load without cookies and create an entirely new session for the user?

For example: could I include an `<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com">` on a site such that even a currently logged-in StackOverflow user would not be automatically logged in?

An "incognito mode" iframe, if you will.

Answer (score 1):

The HTML5 sandbox attribute (without allow-same-origin keyword) prevents an iframe from reading/writing cookies. This is true for both same-origin and cross-origin iframes.

The allow-scripts attribute will enable JS, but will not interfere with restrictions on cookies.

`<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="..."></iframe>`

-via Chava G 
[Recommended method to prevent any content inside iframe from setting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837450/recommended-method-to-prevent-any-content-inside-iframe-from-setting-cookies)

Answer (score 0):

if you want iframe don't set cookies and render correctly:

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-scripts" src="..."></iframe>
```

if you want only not showing iframe:

```
  <iframe id="FR" src="">
```

in java script:

```
document.getElementById("FR").style.display = "none";
document.getElementById("FR").style.visibility = "hidden";
```