# Vimeo embed do not track

Tags: iframe, vimeo

I am embedding a Vimeo video, however, I wish to add their "Do not track" function.

I have added the URL parameter

```
?dnt=1
```

```
              <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/12341234123?dnt=1"/>
```

however, I still see cookies from Vimeo when loading the site.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837450/recommended-method-to-prevent-any-content-inside-iframe-from-setting-cookies

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recommended method to prevent any content inside iframe from setting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837450/recommended-method-to-prevent-any-content-inside-iframe-from-setting-cookies)