# Soundcloud embedded player (iframe) without cookies

Tags: html, cookies, iframe, sandbox, soundcloud

When using an embedded Soundcloud player in a `iframe`:

```html
<iframe width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251273255&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
```

it stores cookies.

**How to embed a Soundcloud player without cookies?**

Note: I already tried `<iframe ... sandbox>` or even `sandbox="allow-scripts"` as suggested in [Recommended method to prevent any content inside iframe from setting cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837450/recommended-method-to-prevent-any-content-inside-iframe-from-setting-cookies) but then the player doesn't work.

Comment: [Did you look into this?](https://www.clym.io/embed-soundcloud-content-without-the-cookies/#:~:text=SoundCloud%20like%20any%20other%20third,iframe%20into%20a%20Clym%20iframe.)

Comment: @Coja I'm looking for a solution without using a third-party service.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms" width="100%" height="300" scrolling="no" frameborder="no" allow="autoplay" src="https://w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251273255&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
```

Please try this `sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts allow-popups allow-forms"`

Comment: I tried this, but then cookies are stored (see your browser Developer Tools, and then "Storage" tab > you'll see cookies from soundcloud.com)

Comment: For me sandbox="allow-same-origin allow-scripts" is enough, but that's new : we post a new song every 2 weeks, and it's the first time we have to add this...
It seems that removing the sandbox attr also works BTW.

Answer (score -2):

This question is similar to:
[Disable Cookies Inside A Frame/Iframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3330906/disable-cookies-inside-a-frame-iframe)

But here is the code you need:

```html
<iframe  sandbox="allow-scripts" src="//w.soundcloud.com/player/?url=https%3A//api.soundcloud.com/tracks/251273255&color=%23ff5500&auto_play=false&hide_related=false&show_comments=true&show_user=true&show_reposts=false&show_teaser=true&visual=true"></iframe>
```

This code blocks cookies and allows cache and cache is not cookies. Although similar they are not the same. Here is proof that it takes only cache and not cookies.

[image: Allows cache]

Comment: The answer to the question you linked is "use sandbox mode". I mentioned in my question that I already tried sandbox mode, without success. It doesn't work.

Comment: Can you please add some code to show how you made it working? Thank you.

Comment: Did this answer your question?

Comment: It simply does not work @VarunW. Can you please give a link to an example html page showing your technique? With `sandbox="allow-scripts"` the player doesn't show for me.

Comment: https://www.cookieinfo.net/en/knowledge-base/iframe-cookie-consent/ and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44837450/recommended-method-to-prevent-any-content-inside-iframe-from-setting-cookies

Comment: What os are you using and are you sure cookies are saved? Try deleting souncloud cookies and then try this script. Cache are not cookies so please dont get those confused. Try to find out what is getting stored cookies or cache. If possible please attach an image of the cookies in you laptop.